# Communicating an incrementer between two classes

Tags: java

In my program I have two conversion counters currently split between two different classes which look like this.

The conversion counters are in two different panels(split through the middle) which are in two different classes which are declared and called in a third main class.

[image]

And after you do some conversion's they each individually counted them until cleared.

[image]

What I need to do but I cannot figure out how is to make one conversion counter that will work between both classes and operate for both of the converters. It needs to count the conversions for both of the converters and clear with one button only.

Can somebody please guide me in what to do? Here is my attached code for the main class holding both panels and for one of the converters (both converters are exact duplicate apart from different names in the list and different values in the conversion factors so you can run the program with two copies of the first one.

Main Class

```
package autassignment;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Converter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Converter");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);      

        // Create a new master panel
        JPanel masterPanel = new JPanel();

        // Use a box layout to stack the panels
        masterPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(masterPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        MainPanel panel = new MainPanel(); 
        frame.setJMenuBar(panel.setupMenu());

        // Create the new currency panel
        CurrencyPanel currencyPanel = new CurrencyPanel();

        // Add the sub-panels to the master panel 
        masterPanel.add(panel);
        masterPanel.add(currencyPanel);

        // Add the master panel to the frame
        frame.getContentPane().add(masterPanel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        panel.currencyPanel = currencyPanel;
        currencyPanel.mainPanel = panel;
    }


}
```

CurrencyConverter Class

```
package autassignment;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class CurrencyPanel extends JPanel {



    //declaring everything before using it
    private final static String[] list = { "Euro (EUR)", "US Dollars (USD)", "Australian Dollars (AUD)", "Canadian Dollars (CAD)", "Icelandic Króna (ISK)", "United Arab Emirates Dirham (AED)", "South African Rand (ZAR)", "The Baht (THB)"};
    private JTextField textField;
    private JLabel label;
    private JLabel countLabel;
    private JComboBox<String> combo;
    int convCount=0;
    boolean reverse;
    public MainPanel mainPanel;
    JCheckBox reverseCheck;


    //start of my menu
    JMenuBar setupMenu() {

        //main bar to hold everything
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        //menu items
        //menomnic key events added to main menuitems
        JMenu filebar = new JMenu("File");
        filebar.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        JMenu helpbar = new JMenu("Help");
        helpbar.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_H);

        //menu items added to the JMENUBAR
        menuBar.add(filebar);
        menuBar.add(helpbar);

        //sub menu items added to menu items
        //actionlisteners added to submenuitems
        //menmonic key events added to subemenuitems
        JMenuItem exitbar = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        exitbar.addActionListener(new CloseListener());
        exitbar.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        filebar.add(exitbar);

        JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About");
        about.addActionListener(new AboutListener());
        about.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        helpbar.add(about);

        //command which displays the menu bar
        return menuBar;
    }


    CurrencyPanel() {

        ActionListener listener = new ConvertListener();
        ActionListener listener2 = new ClearListener();
        ItemListener listener3 = new ReverseListener();

        combo = new JComboBox<String>(list);
        combo.addActionListener(listener); //convert values when option changed

        JLabel inputLabel = new JLabel("Enter value:");

        JButton convertButton = new JButton("Convert");
        convertButton.addActionListener(listener); // convert values when pressed
        JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
        clearButton.addActionListener(listener2);


        label = new JLabel("---");
        countLabel = new JLabel();
        textField = new JTextField(5);
        reverseCheck = new JCheckBox("Reverse Conversion");
        reverseCheck.addItemListener(listener3);
        textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                int key = e.getKeyCode();
                if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    String text = textField.getText().trim();

                    if (text.isEmpty() == false) {
                        convCount++;

                        double value = Double.parseDouble(text);

                        // the factor applied during the conversion
                        double factor = 0;

                        // the offset applied during the conversion.
                        double offset = 0;

                        // Setup the correct factor/offset values depending on
                        // required
                        // conversion
                        switch (combo.getSelectedIndex()) {

                        case 0: // EUR
                            if(reverse==false) {
                                factor = 1.359;
                                break;
                            } if(reverse==true) {
                                factor = 0.73;
                                break;
                            }

                        case 1: // USD
                            if(reverse==false) {
                                factor = 1.34;
                                break;
                            } if(reverse==true) {
                                factor = 1.82;
                                break;
                            }

                        case 2: // AUD
                            if(reverse==false) {
                                factor = 1.756;
                                break;
                            } if(reverse==true) {
                                factor = 0.62;
                                break;
                            }

                        case 3: // CAD
                            if(reverse==false) {
                                factor = 1.71;
                                break;
                            } if(reverse==true) {
                                factor = 0.21;
                                break;
                            }

                        case 4: // ISK
                            if(reverse==false) {
                                factor = 140.84;
                                break;
                            } if(reverse==true) {
                                factor = 3.28;
                                break;
                            }

                        case 5: // AED
                            if(reverse==false) {
                                factor = 4.92;
                                break;
                            } if(reverse==true) {
                                factor = -272.15;
                                break;
                            }

                        case 6: // ZAR
                            if(reverse==false) {
                                factor = 17.84;
                                break;
                            } if(reverse==true) {
                                factor = 2.47;
                                break;
                            }

                        case 7: // THB
                            if(reverse==false) {
                                factor = 43.58;
                                break;
                            } if(reverse==true) {
                                factor = 2.47;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        double result = factor * value + offset;
                        double roundedresult = Math.round(result *100)/100.00;

                        label.setText(Double.toString(roundedresult));
                        countLabel.setText("conversions: " + convCount);
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        add(combo);
        add(reverseCheck);
        add(inputLabel);
        add(textField);
        add(convertButton);
        add(clearButton);
        add(label);
        add(countLabel);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 80));
        setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    }


    private class ConvertListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            String text = textField.getText().trim();

            if (text.isEmpty() == false) {

                convCount++;

                double value = Double.parseDouble(text);

                // the factor applied during the conversion
                double factor = 0;

                // the offset applied during the conversion.
                double offset = 0;

                // Setup the correct factor/offset values depending on
                // required
                // conversion
                switch (combo.getSelectedIndex()) {

                case 0: // EUR
                    if(reverse==false) {
                        factor = 1.359;
                        break;
                    } if(reverse==true) {
                        factor = 0.73;
                        break;
                    }

                case 1: // USD
                    if(reverse==false) {
                        factor = 1.34;
                        break;
                    } if(reverse==true) {
                        factor = 1.82;
                        break;
                    }

                case 2: // AUD
                    if(reverse==false) {
                        factor = 1.756;
                        break;
                    } if(reverse==true) {
                        factor = 0.62;
                        break;
                    }

                case 3: // CAD
                    if(reverse==false) {
                        factor = 1.71;
                        break;
                    } if(reverse==true) {
                        factor = 0.21;
                        break;
                    }

                case 4: // ISK
                    if(reverse==false) {
                        factor = 140.84;
                        break;
                    } if(reverse==true) {
                        factor = 3.28;
                        break;
                    }

                case 5: // AED
                    if(reverse==false) {
                        factor = 4.92;
                        break;
                    } if(reverse==true) {
                        factor = -272.15;
                        break;
                    }

                case 6: // ZAR
                    if(reverse==false) {
                        factor = 17.84;
                        break;
                    } if(reverse==true) {
                        factor = 2.47;
                        break;
                    }

                case 7: // THB
                    if(reverse==false) {
                        factor = 43.58;
                        break;
                    } if(reverse==true) {
                        factor = 2.47;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                double result = factor * value + offset;
                double roundedresult = Math.round(result *100)/100.00;


                label.setText(Double.toString(roundedresult));
                countLabel.setText("conversions: " + convCount);
            }
        }
    }


    private class ReverseListener implements ItemListener {


        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {

            if (reverseCheck.isSelected()) {
                reverse = true;
    //          System.out.println("test test test");             <---- Test
            } 

            else {
                reverse = false;
            }

        }
    }

    private class ClearListener implements ActionListener {


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            label.setText("---");
            convCount=0;
            countLabel.setText("Conversions: " + convCount);

        }
    }   




    // actionlistener exit
    private class CloseListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // closes window
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    // aboutlistener exit
    private class AboutListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is my application designed to convert different values for you from your set paramaters. This is created by Daniel Siwiec. ©Daniel Siwiec 2018");
        }
    }}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could do, is instead of tracking your conversions in an int, track them in another class.

```
public class ConvertTracker {
    private int conversions;

    public ConvertTracker() {
        conversions = 0;
    }

    public int getConversions() {
        return conversions;
    }

    public int incrementConversions() {
        conversions++;
        return conversions;
    }

    public void resetConversions() {
        conversions = 0;
    }
}
```

Then pass the same instance of `ConvertTracker` between both of your panels.